# DocumentDB Physical Partition RU's Issue

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am created Collection with 250GB, 50000RU's with Partition key,it showing physically creates 25 Physical Partitions and each partition have 2000 RU's are allocated.

i am adding data with 3 different partition key's and it will store in the any of 25 partition. my question is, assume 3 partition key data are save in 3 different Physical Partitions and i am sending request to create documents for those 3 physical partition.if those Partition RU's are required more than 2000 RU's(exceed the RU's allocated limit),will DocumentDB allocate other Physical Partition free RU's to required Physical Partition or fixed to particular Partition?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As the official document mentioned about [Partitioning and provisioned throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#partitioning-and-provisioned-throughput):

> When DocumentDB stores documents, it distributes them evenly among partitions based on the partition key value. **The throughput is also distributed evenly among the available partitions i.e. the throughput per partition = (total throughput per collection)/ (number of partitions)**.
>
> In order to achieve the full throughput of the collection, **you must choose a partition key that allows you to evenly distribute requests among a number of distinct partition key values**.

> if those Partition RU's are required more than 2000 RU's(exceed the RU's allocated limit),will DocumentDB allocate other Physical Partition free RU's to required Physical Partition or fixed to particular Partition?

Based on my understanding, each Physical Partition has the fixed throughput based on the available partitions.

Comment: you mean One physical partition RU's are not allocate another RU's if request are high for that partition?

if RU's are fixed that Physical Partition and my partitions keys are less than Physical partitions means it will be unused until i add more partition keys?

Comment: As the document states that DocumentDB creates a small number of physical partitions behind each collection based on **storage size** and **provisioned throughput**, and when the size of a specific partition is full, then DocumentDB would automatically move the partition keys without impact the availability of your collection. But I do not see anything about re-allocating RU when the throughput of a partition is overload.